# R Prophet error: Dataframe must have columns 'ds' and 'y' with the dates and values respectively

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I have a data frame which I generated like this:

```
> library(prophet)
> Date  <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), "years"), 3)
> Group <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5)
> Value <- runif(15, 0, 100)
> Expln <- runif(15, 0, 100)
> 
> df <- data.frame(Date, Group, Value, Expln)
> 
> df
         Date Group     Value     Expln
1  2010-01-01     A 93.019346 39.446235
2  2011-01-01     A  3.389022 38.371961
3  2012-01-01     A  3.719541 93.922155
4  2013-01-01     A 11.267414 64.716674
5  2014-01-01     A 84.978091 18.808735
6  2010-01-01     B 13.723934 54.930282
7  2011-01-01     B 84.698500 52.628834
8  2012-01-01     B 23.743542 61.603183
9  2013-01-01     B 45.178280 72.345074
10 2014-01-01     B 80.779443 96.847733
11 2010-01-01     C 67.818529  9.020017
12 2011-01-01     C 46.020754 83.168086
13 2012-01-01     C 99.266430 61.400123
14 2013-01-01     C 17.218871 91.511166
15 2014-01-01     C  8.624025 39.995071
```

I try to apply `prophet` to a single group and it gives me an error:

```
> dfx = df[df$Group == "A",]
> dfx = dfx[c(1, 3, 4)]
> dfx
        Date     Value    Expln
1 2010-01-01 93.019346 39.44623
2 2011-01-01  3.389022 38.37196
3 2012-01-01  3.719541 93.92216
4 2013-01-01 11.267414 64.71667
5 2014-01-01 84.978091 18.80874
> m = prophet()
> m = add_regressor(m, 'Expln')
> m = fit.prophet(m, dfx)
Error in fit.prophet(m, dfx) : 
  Dataframe must have columns 'ds' and 'y' with the dates and values respectively.
```

Why do I get this error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Prophet is saying it wants to see columns called `ds` and `y`, which don't exist in `dfx`. For instance, run this first: `dfx$ds = dfx$Date; dfx$y = dfx$Value`. Or rename them upstream where you define them.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, I needed to rename `Date` and `Value` into `ds` and `y`:

```
> library(prophet)
> Date  <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), "years"), 3)
> Group <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5)
> Value <- runif(15, 0, 100)
> Expln <- runif(15, 0, 100)
> 
> df <- data.frame(ds = Date, Group, y = Value, Expln)
> 
> df
           ds Group         y    Expln
1  2010-01-01     A 44.907724 18.21944
2  2011-01-01     A  5.110549 88.22997
3  2012-01-01     A 41.627854 81.31806
4  2013-01-01     A 87.261591 31.91806
5  2014-01-01     A 82.931747 89.88972
6  2010-01-01     B 27.985192 53.98613
7  2011-01-01     B 82.574708 35.00410
8  2012-01-01     B 21.125819 56.96952
9  2013-01-01     B 12.400783 44.10640
10 2014-01-01     B 50.554773 49.89784
11 2010-01-01     C  2.086168 72.10425
12 2011-01-01     C 54.932624 58.57923
13 2012-01-01     C 52.649403 50.39760
14 2013-01-01     C 91.927291 56.70027
15 2014-01-01     C 25.771383 80.64624

> dfx = df[df$Group == "A",]
> dfx = dfx[c(1, 3, 4)]
> dfx
          ds         y    Expln
1 2010-01-01 44.907724 18.21944
2 2011-01-01  5.110549 88.22997
3 2012-01-01 41.627854 81.31806
4 2013-01-01 87.261591 31.91806
5 2014-01-01 82.931747 89.88972

> m <- prophet()
> m <- add_regressor(m = m, name = 'Expln')
> m <- fit.prophet(m = m, df = df)
Disabling weekly seasonality. Run prophet with weekly.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
n.changepoints greater than number of observations. Using 11
```